# a condition that the element fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 90 divs in my page that they'll come up with different delays.
now, I wnat to write a condition that says  (( If )) all of them are visible, do something!!!

when I wrote that If visibility sets, or if opacity of that elements are 1 or any other style attributes are sets, do something, because the element is hidden in the first time the page is loading, the condition is NOT TRUE and the program don't do any thing...

Please Guide me that what should I do...!!!

for example here is some of fadeIn s :

```
 var temp = 1000;
    var f = 100;
    $('.pixel#p38').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p6').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p22').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p18').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p53').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p56').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p59').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p61').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p73').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p18').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p72').delay(temp+=f).fadeIn(f);
    $('.pixel#p17').delay(temp).fadeIn(f);
```

Comment: where are the scripts that test the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
var total = $('div.pixel').length,
    visible = $('div.pixel:visible').length;

if(total === visible)
    //do stuff
```

You could also check if a div is currently being animated using

```
$('div.pixel').is(':animated');
```